# SAP WEB IDE - Fiori Mobile option has disappeared from menu

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

The option to build a Fiori Mobile app has disappeared from the project menu in SAP WEB IDE.

It was working a week ago...

What's happened and can anyone else still see the option.

(SAP WEB IDE Full Stack - Trail Version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check destinations at cockpit . You should have fiorimobileapi,mobileservices destinations.

Comment: Connectivity Issue... All is well now. Thanks